# Having trouble starting a bounty

Tags: support, status-completed, bounty

I am a relatively new user, with 114 reputation points. I'd like to start a bounty on [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/reading-material-about-gender-studies-feminism) question, but I'm not seeing any link. Any ideas?

Comment: It should be possible, since you only need 75 rep for that. I see the corresponding link...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've already found the answer to your question but for completeness, the bounty option is just below the comments on the main question and above the "Answers" text. It can only be started after a question has been posted for at least 2 days.

For more information, see the [Bounty help page](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).